# "Database" in c (not actual database, just a simple thing)

Tags: c, database

The main idea of the code below is to let me add, delete etc portions of the arrays so that it looks more or less like a store's database (did this because I have no idea how to use pointers and etc). I got the thing almost figured it out, but i am having 2 big problems:
The first problem is that I get a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I run the code and select case 1. I don't even know what the error means so I don't see how can I fix it.
The second problem which is probably my biggest, can anybody tell me how can I store the arrays in a file in such a way that when I run the program again, the arrays won't be empty, but will take their elements from a file, and save in the same file when I exit (that's why I used the word database).

> include stdio.h
> include stdbool.h
>
> int main()

```
{ bool bExit = false;
  int select, i, price[5], amount[5];
  char *name[5];
```

> do
>
> ```
> { printf("What would you like to do ?:\n");
>   printf("1) Add products \n");
>   printf("2) Delete products \n");
>   printf("3) Find product by name (shows position and price) \n");
>   printf("4) Find product by position (shows name and price) \n");
>   printf("6) Display all info of all products  \n");
>   printf("7) Modify amount of existing product \n");
>   printf("8) Modify price of existing product \n");
>   printf("9 Exit \n");
>   scanf("%d", &select);
> ```

```
  switch (select)
    {
    case 1:
      {
        for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
          {
            printf("Name: ");
            scanf("%c\n", *name[i]);
            printf("Price: ");
            scanf("%d\n", price[i]);
            printf("Amount: ");
            scanf("%d\n", amount[i]);
          }
        break;
      }
    case 2:
```

... bla bla bla ...

```
    default:
      {
        printf("Good Bye \n");
        bExit = true;
        break;
      }
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question. You have two separate issues here: segfaulting and writing to a file. Also, you should be able to find plenty of information about both with a simple search.

Comment: Have you considered using an Excel (or any other similar tool) spreadsheet for that?

Comment: Thank you for all your replies, I will try tomorrow and see what i can do, sorry for the double question, I didn't tought it would worth 2 posts. (And btw i searched for 2-3 hours didn't find anything similar, only really tough coding that only confused me more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use any pointer for char *name[5]. Use char name[5] instead. Probably the segmentation fault comes from this statement

```
scanf("%c\n", *name[i]);
```

for the second question create a file and open it whenever you want to read/write. Something like

```
File *fptr=fopen("database","w");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\n",name[i]);

}
```

take a look in the link here:http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't allocate any memory for your names

char* name[5]  is just an array of 5 pointers to chars.

you could do  `char name[5][100]`  its fixed to 100 chars.

Going forward, you really need to alocate memory for strings, and also allocate memory for "database" entries.

2. You need to save your "database" to disk, and then load it again when it starts

Answer (score 0):

Create a big array (maybe a vector<>) where you save all prices and names etc. Then when you use scanf for price and amount use & (like scanf("%d", &price[i]) ). 
Then you write the values on a .txt file (you can use c++ ofstream, google for that) and when you execute your code, first of all you read previous values from your file (using ifstream).

Comment: The question is about C. C does not have templates.

Comment: Ok so instead using a vector you can simpky use a big array and instead using ifstream and ofstream, you can use FILE *in, *out and fopen, fprintf and fscanf, which are C functions...